# python casting variables with type as argument

Tags: python, types, casting

Is there a casting function which takes both the variable and type to cast to? Such as:

```
cast_var = cast_fn(original_var, type_to_cast_to)
```

I want to use it as an efficient way to cycle through a list of input parameters parsed from a string, some will need to be cast as int, bool, float etc...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to cast?

Comment: Can you add some more information on how you wish to use this? Else, I'd be tempted to just ship you off with a: "Look into `astype`", which can be used on numpy.ndarrays..

Comment: Why not just do so explicitly? `a = '5', b = int(a)`?

Comment: Why do you need a separate function when the type parameter itself can be used directly as a sort of factory function.

Comment: @pstatix: right, or in general `cast_var = type_to_cast_to(original_variable)`.  In Python I see no need for the existence of a function that OP is asking for.

Comment: to be completely fair, @PaulCornelius the `map` function is somewhat alike what he might be needing ..

Comment: @PaulCornelius Exactly right. At worst, if the OP is unaware of valid type, they can do a type cast function which tests in `try/except` and catches `ValueError`, thus proceeding to next desired type. Beyond that, no need.

Comment: @Uvar `map` does in fact apply the function (say `int()`) to a variable/iterable; but what returns is a `map object`. Why bother when you can simply "cast" the type onto the original variable and store in a new one?

Comment: Indeed, since all types are represented by callable class objects, there is no need for a separate operator or syntax to do such type conversions.

Comment: @pstatix for applying it to a list, instead of just 1 item; to give an example. :)

Comment: @Uvar Sure, if you need to do it to a list; you still return a `map object` and none of the variables are stored into new variables; they would've had to have been stored in a container of sorts.

Comment: Hi all, please see the above edit, sorry should have been more clear to begin.

Comment: Hi all, please see the above edit, sorry should have been more clear to begin.

Comment: @JohnJos So what's wrong with all the answers you already got, e.g. the comment by Paul Cornelius above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All Python types are callable

```
new_val = int(old_val)
```

so no special function is needed. Indeed, what you are asking for is effectively just an `apply` function

```
new_val = apply(int, old_val)
```

which exists in Python 2, but was removed from Python 3 as it was never necessary; any expression that could be passed as the first argument to `apply` can always be used with the call "operator":

```
apply(expr, *args) == expr(*args)
```

Comment: I liked that `apply()` was a function instead of just some syntax.  A function is a first-class objects and can be passed around, but you can't pass around syntax.  As one example, I sometimes used `@apply` for intialisation functions that should run at import time.  (I know this is a bit hacky, and I also know that I can simply define my own `apply()` in Python 3.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach You can use `types.FunctionType.__call__` instead :)

Comment: Yeah, that could be assigned to `apply`, but the main point of `apply()` was the convenience.  I wonder why there isn't even `operator.call()`.

Comment: I usually don't think of the call syntax as an operator, but I don't have a strong argument to back up that opinion. It sounds like a valid suggestion for they python-ideas mailing list; the relocation of `reduce` to the `functools` module certainly seems like a good precedent.

Comment: (Looks like there was some related discussion [last summer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-ideas/ES9f2oc7W8A); not sure anything ever came of it. Someone mentioned `functools.apply` as if it already existed, although it doesn't appear to. That would be another idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
This works:

```
>>> t = int
>>> s = "9"
>>> t(s)
```

Or a full example:

```
def convert(type_id, value):
    return type_id(value)

convert(int, "3")  # --> 3
convert(str, 3.0)  # --> '3.0'
```